# android game control

Tags: android

Help me with control in my adnroid game)

I have 2 buttons: 
to move left and to move right. If we press left sprite moves left and if we press right sprite moves.

Here is code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
                event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){ 
        touchX = event.getX();
    }
    if(touchX == arrow_leftX){
        gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
    }
    else if(touchX == arrow_leftX){
        playerX = playerX - xSpeed;
    }
    else if(touchX == arrow_rightX){
        playerX = playerX - xSpeed;
    }
    else if(touchX == arrow_rightX){
        gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

**So the Problem is:**

> it moves only left, i dont know how to move right ?

Answer (score 1):

```
The Problem is here i think

else if(touchX == arrow_rightX){
        playerX = playerX - xSpeed;
    }


else if(touchX == arrow_rightX){

// Here You can see that you are again subtracting the x axis from
// playerX 
// it is clear that you are moving your image with this 
// but if you decrease value from x it shall move to lext
// to  move it to  right you need to increase its value 

        playerX = playerX + xSpeed;
    }
```